# How to bring application to foreground programatically in ios 9 using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to bring application to foreground programatically from background when the device receives a notification (without user interactions).

Whenever a notification occurs, I'm able to parse the data using

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {}
```

but unable to load UI.

How can I bring app to foreground?

By the way, I have enabled "Background mode" and checked "remote notifications" in xcode.

Comment: With background mode and remote notification, iOS will call application:didReceiveRemoteNotification IF content-available = 1 in the notification payload

Comment: content-available = 1 -- for silent notification ,

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can only send the user a notification to ask if they want to open the app (or answer a question asked by the notification without even bothering to open the app).

Answer (score 1):

after user click on Notification it will take user to foregrond otherwise you cannot go to foreground directly

Answer (score 1):

**It cannot be possible without user interaction** ,

you can sent the APNS to device to tell the user to bring the application to foreground, if user interact that you can proceed further procedure

Comment: Documentation page cannot be found.

Comment: @kumar -- sorry bro I removed ,

Comment: @kumar -- do u need any aditional help related to this